# My Audit Trail Isn't Working

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-data-macro

I am having a problem getting my audit trail started. If I change "Item Number" on tbl_MBRSummary, a record should be made on tbl_AuditChanges_Tables. This isn't happening and I don't know why. I followed directions to a T from [ScottGem](https://scottgem.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/audit-trail-using-data-macros-2/)... Is there something wrong with this setup?

[image: Screenshot of current DataMacro]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro you're showing us is for `Tbl_AuditChanges_Tables`, not for `Tbl_MBRSummary`, and thus won't trigger when you're updating that table.

You need to create the macro on the actual table you're changing, and you need to make sure the `If` statement actually includes a field you're changing. If you do that, it should work.

Comment: I appreciate your help. That was the issue.